# ¿Qué se hace con las preguntas en inglés que están en Stack Overflow en español?

Tags: soporte, cierre-de-preguntas, motivos-de-cierre, reportes

¿Es correcto escribir preguntas en inglés en Stack Overflow en español?

Si no, ¿qué se procede a realizar?

Lo digo por esta pregunta: (10k+) [C programming: while loop with a read and a switch case function just work once](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74852/c-programming-while-loop-with-a-read-and-a-switch-case-function-just-work-once)

Comment: Yo suelo reportar éstas preguntas o solicitar en un comentario su traducción, según tenga el día.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, no es correcto.

En tu caso, debes tocar el botón **reportar**, porque tu reputación es menor a 3000, y luego elegir, **debería ser cerrada...**. En caso contrario hay que tocar el botón, **cerrar**. Haciendo esto, aparecerá un cartel con varias opciones.

Luego sigue estos pasos.

1. Elegir **no relacionado porque...**
2. Elegir **La pregunta está escrita en inglés. El idioma oficial de este sitio es español.**
3. Tocar el botón azul **Votar para cerrar**.

Si te quedan suficientes reportes que puedes hacer en un día, lo podrás hacer. En tu caso, este no es un voto de cierre inmediato, pero será enviada a la cola de revisiones para que puedan mirarla otros usuarios, con reputación mayor a 3000.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, justamente tenía duda con ello :)