# Pregunta que está en la cola de revisiones pero no tiene ningún voto de cierre

Tags: soporte, votos-de-cierre, reportes, revisiones

Entré a la cola de revisiones de votos de cierre y me apareció la siguiente pregunta [Error en SQL: Data truncated for column](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/77400/error-en-sql-data-truncated-for-column), pero viendo los motivos de cierre veo que no se ha votado por ninguno. Incluso, al ver directamente en la pregunta no tiene ningún voto de cierre registrado.

La cola de revisiones:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es: ¿por qué está en la cola de revisiones si no tiene ningún voto de cierre registrado?

Comment: En realidad en tu captura pone que ha sido reportada como "demasiado amplia". En realidad llevo varios días observando que hay preguntas en la cola de revisión que incluso no tienen ningún tipo de reporte (en este caso sería por demasiado amplia) y aún así aparecen en la cola de revisión de cerrar preguntas. La verdad que creo que puede haber algún problema con eso.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero No, es así el sitio... La pregunta fue reportada en vez de votar para cerrar. El reporte no cuenta como voto de cierre.

Comment: @ArtEze Gracias por la corrección. Sin embargo, hay veces que aparecen en la cola sin votos de cierre ni de reporte (si encuentro alguna abro una discusión aquí en meta). ¿Eso a que puede deberse?

Comment: @Francisco cuando no tienen votos de cierre, significa que un usuario puso reportar - debería ser cerrada - motivo. Los reportes no los vas a ver. Sólo un moderador los ve, y son confidenciales.

Comment: Ya que estamos, es importante destacar también que lo que aparece en la [Línea de tiempo de la publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/77400/timeline) da información útil, pero para usuarios normales no constan las revisiones que aún no han concluido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es porque fue reportada, supuestamente por un usuario con reputación menor a 3000.

Los reportes no cuentan como voto de cierre.

Comment: ¿Es decir que si un usuario con reputación menor a 3k vota para cerrarla, no cuenta el voto y la pregunta entra a las colas de revisión?

Comment: @Flxtr Ahí edité la respuesta... No es obligatorio que sea un usuario con reputación menor a 3000... Lo que digo es que emitir un reporte, es diferente a un voto de cierre.

Comment: @Flxtr Mira esta respuesta que hice hace algunos días... [¿Qué se hace con las preguntas en inglés que están en Stack Overflow en español?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2101/13558)

Comment: De la pregunta en cuestión, ¿sabes cuál fue el motivo del reporte? Me sigue causando duda ya que no logro comprender cómo un reporte puede terminar en las colas para cerrar la pregunta.

Comment: @Flxtr En tu captura está eso: Dice "demasiado amplia".

Comment: Hasta donde entiendo, un moderador debería rechazar un reporte de cierre de un usuario de 3k+